# why does goto loop stop iteration when condition is FALSE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, goto

I am trying to iterate through the NORTHWIND data in SQL Server as such:

```
DECLARE @Vcatid INT = 1
DECLARE @Vcatname NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Vdesc NVARCHAR(255)

GOTO_Table:
    SELECT @Vcatid = categoryid,
           @Vcatname = categoryname,
           @Vdesc = description
    FROM categories
    WHERE 1=1
    AND categoryid = @Vcatid
    PRINT 'category id is: ' + CAST(@Vcatid AS VARCHAR) + ' category name is ' + @Vcatname + ' description is: ' + @Vdesc --+ ' picture is: ' @Vpic
    SET @Vcatid = @Vcatid + 1

IF @Vcatname LIKE '%A%'
GOTO GOTO_Table
ELSE
PRINT 'No more categories compatible with the condition'
```

Basically, there are 5 categories which have the letter 'a' in their name:

```
select *
from Categories
where 1=1
and categoryname LIKE '%a%'
```

My problem:
After 2 iterraions, the query stops and gives an output for categoryid 1 and 2 only, where categoryid 2 doesn't even have the letter 'a' in its name.

[SELECT * FROM categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuVv0.jpg)
[SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categoryname LIKE 'a'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYM1w.jpg) 
[Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb0av.jpg)

I have tried using a while loop, but it just made the iterration go forever

Comment: The 2nd row doesn't have an `a`, so the `GOTO` isn't entered and thus the batch ends. You aren't looping through all the values that have an `a`, you're looping until you find a value without an `a`.

Comment: I think the question is rather, what is your loop supposed to accomplish. Goto shouldn't be used to loop, i suspect what you want is a cursor rather than whatever you're doing

Comment: so why does the output include category 2, which doesn't have asn 'a' ? and also: when I check the iteration, I can see that ' 9 Rows were effected'. How can I loop over all item in the table?

Comment: Because what you expect the code to do and what it does aren't the same thing, @doron . As I mentioned you are "looping" until you you get to a row without an `a`, and the 2nd row is the *first* row without an `a` so that's where the loop ends. What are you *Actually* trying to do? Why do you want to loop at all? T-SQL ios a set based language, so why not use a set based solution? Why do you want 9 datasets with 1 row each, rather than 1 dataset with 9 rows?

Comment: I think the question is why are you using a GOTO and loops in the first place?

Comment: I think you have your condition backwards, should be `IF @Vcatname NOT LIKE '%A%' GOTO GOTO_Table` but yeah, you should just use a window function or a subquery for this, rather than messing around with loops.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have your condition backwards and you actually want `IF @Vcatname NOT LIKE '%A%'`. Or possibly you just need to put the condition around the `PRINT` and unconditionally loop.

But you don't need, and shouldn't use, loops in the first place. Just do a simple select.

Either a simple `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT
  categoryid,
  categoryname,
  description
FROM categories
WHERE categoryname LIKE '%A%' ;
```

Or if you want all rows up to the first `A` inclusive, then use a windowed count

```sql
SELECT
  categoryid,
  categoryname,
  description
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      count = COUNT(CASE WHEN categoryname LIKE '%A%' THEN 1 END)
            OVER (ORDER BY categoryid ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
    FROM categories
) c
WHERE count = 0;
```